# Use regex to find a substring with hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I'm new at regex for character matching and I need a regex to **NOT MATCH** the substring *SL-T* and character *T* . The regex for the character *T* cannot detect the *T* character in the substring *SL-T* . I have looked at other questions and nothing has really helped me. This is as close as I can get before negating the expression.

```
(SL-T)|(T)
```

I'm using JavaScript regex.

Here is a small portion of data. All lines except 1,4, and 6 need to be matched by the expression.

```
T         //1
W-R  
T-SB  
T         //4
ST  
SL-T      //6
SL  
TSGE  
SR  
ST
```

Comment: Could you provide a list (perhaps 10 items) of inputs, and say whether each should be accepted or rejected by the regex? I'm not quite sure from your wording what you want

Comment: Also, it is important to know what kind of regex engine you have available. PCRE? Basic/Extended (as with grep, sed, etc) ?

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?!(?:SL-)?T$)
```

Starting at the beginning of the line, it uses negative lookahead to make sure the string does not consist of an optional "SL-" and then the letter "T" followed by the end of the string.